# MySQL: memory requirements for django app with 1 big table (460M rows)

Tags: mysql, performance, memory, optimization, query-performance

I have created a django app that is running on virtual machine. All db tables are rather small (up to 1M rows) but recently I was asked to add a big table (460M rows).

```
CREATE TABLE `genescorrelation` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `correlation` double NOT NULL,
 `gene1_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `gene2_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `c_gene1_id_6b1d81605661118_fk_genes_gene_entrez`   (`gene1_id`),
KEY `gene2_gene1_idx1` (`gene2_id`,`gene1_id`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=92345005 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The query that user will run (up to 10 genes):

```
 SELECT gene1_id, AVG(correlation) AS avg FROM genescorrelation 
 WHERE gene2_id IN (176829, 176519, 176230) 
 GROUP BY gene1_id ORDER BY NULL
```

Currently I have imported around 89M rows and the query is slow. It would take around 30-40 seconds for 3 or 4 genes.

I think my VM is too weak because it was a default set up (for smaller project/database). Currently it has just 2GB RAM and 36GB space.

I need to ask to set up prod machine.

What are the memory/space suggestion for this kind of set up?
Is there anything that could be done in MySQL config?
Is there anything else I can do to speed up a query?

Any hints appreciated, thanks.

*FYI, I asked my initial question on so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969964/mysql-slow-avg-query-for-411m-rows. After that I was trying to add the suggested index (gene2, gene1) but didn't have enough space, so dropped the table and reimported 90M rows.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the query

```
SELECT gene1_id, AVG(correlation) AS avg FROM genescorrelation 
WHERE gene2_id IN (176829, 176519, 176230) 
GROUP BY gene1_id ORDER BY NULL
```

I have four(4) suggestions

## SUGGESTION #1

I see three(3) columns. I recommend making a covering index

```
ALTER TABLE genescorrelation
ADD INDEX gene2_gene1_correlation_idx1 (gene2_id,gene_id,correlation);
```

[The StackOverflow accepted answer already mentioned making this index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31970242/491757). That way, the aggregation never touches the table. All the needed data will come from the index.

Since you already made `gene2_gene1_idx1` here is the fix

```
ALTER TABLE genescorrelation
DROP INDEX gene2_gene1_idx1,
ADD INDEX gene2_gene1_correlation_idx1 (gene2_id,gene_id,correlation);
```

## SUGGESTION #2

You probably need more read threads

Add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
innodb_read_io_threads = 8
```

Restart of mysql is required

## SUGGESTION #3

If the server is just a DB Server, you should reserve up to 75% of RAM for [InnoDB Buffer Pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) or the sum total of all InnoDB Data and Indexes (`SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) InnoDBDataAndIndex FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';`), whichever is smaller.

## SUGGESTION #4 (OPTIONAL)

Change the Query to see break down by `gene2_id`

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(gene2_id,'All Gene2 IDs') gene2,
    IFNULL(gene1_id,'All Gene1 IDs') gene1,
    AVG(correlation) AS avg FROM genescorrelation 
WHERE gene2_id IN (176829, 176519, 176230) 
GROUP BY gene2_id,gene1_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Thanks, Rolando - the covering index made a huge difference! I am going to look into other suggestions as well.

Comment: My DB is on Unix, and according to docs:  increasing the number (innodb_read_io_threads) has no effect; InnoDB always uses the default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `genescorrelation` (
   `correlation` FLOAT NOT NULL,
   `gene1_id` SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL,
   `gene2_id` SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (gene1_id, gene2_id),
  KEY         (gene2_id, gene1_id, correlation)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and reload.

I am assuming that FLOAT, with about 7 significant digits is more than enough for a correlation.  It will save 2GB overall.

Rolando's suggestion took care of one direction; the PK change takes care of the other.